Why can React props take async function as `() => void` instead of `() => Promise<void>`?
Why can React props take async function with () => void signature instead of () => Promise<void> signature without type errors?
Is it intended or misusage?
interface Props {
  onFunc: () => void
}

const Child = ({onFunc}: Props) => {
  // something
}


const Parent = ({onFunc}: Props) => {
  const func: () => Promise<void> = async () => {
    // something
  }

  return <Child onFunc={func}> 
}


What is the problem with that?

I see no type (or functional value) () => void in the question. Can you edit the question to clarify the problem?

right, I meant () => void. I edited the post.

Why are functions returning non-void assignable to function returning void?

@VLAZ That's the answer I'm looking for! This is a bit confusing TS spec though.

A return type of void simply means that the type of the returned value of the function is ignored/unused — even if it's implicitly undefined… or a promise in the case of an async function. This is explained in the TypeScript Handbook section Assignability of Functions:

Return type void
The void return type for functions can produce some unusual, but expected behavior.
Contextual typing with a return type of void does not force functions to not return something. Another way to say this is a contextual function type with a void return type (type voidFunc = () => void), when implemented, can return any other value, but it will be ignored.
Thus, the following implementations of the type () => void are valid:
type voidFunc = () => void;

const f1: voidFunc = () => {
  return true;
};

const f2: voidFunc = () => true;

const f3: voidFunc = function () {
  return true;
};

And when the return value of one of these functions is assigned to another variable, it will retain the type of void:
type voidFunc = () => void;

const f1: voidFunc = () => {
  return true;
};

const f2: voidFunc = () => true;

const f3: voidFunc = function () {
  return true;
};
// ---cut---
const v1 = f1();

const v2 = f2();

const v3 = f3();

This behavior exists so that the following code is valid even though Array.prototype.push returns a number and the Array.prototype.forEach method expects a function with a return type of void.
const src = [1, 2, 3];
const dst = [0];

src.forEach((el) => dst.push(el));

There is one other special case to be aware of, when a literal function definition has a void return type, that function must not return anything.
function f2(): void {
  // @ts-expect-error
  return true;
}

const f3 = function (): void {
  // @ts-expect-error
  return true;
};

For more on void please refer to these other documentation entries:

v2 handbook
FAQ - "Why are functions returning non-void assignable to function returning void?"


